# i dont get the adjustment i want in the buttons

Tags: android

i dont know why buttons dont occupy the all size of linear layaout(vertical) size.
Instead when i use linear layaout(horizontal) they do it.

i leave the linear layaout(vertical) code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your code as it is below;

```
LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight= "1"
    android:text="Button"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight= "1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight= "1"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:weightSum="some_int"` In the linear Layout, and add `android:layout_weight="some_int"` in the child views to occupy the whole linear Layout